# How to use 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' in a Swagger Spec

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am trying to convey that the authentication/security scheme requires setting a header as follows:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

This is what I have based on the [swagger documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securityDefinitionsObject):

```yaml
securityDefinitions:
  APIKey:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
security:
  - APIKey: []
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Bearer auth example
  description: >
    An example for how to use Bearer Auth with OpenAPI / Swagger 2.0.

host: basic-auth-server.herokuapp.com
schemes:
  - http
  - https
securityDefinitions:
  Bearer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
    description: >-
      Enter the token with the `Bearer: ` prefix, e.g. "Bearer abcde12345".
paths:
  /:
    get:
      security:
        - Bearer: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Will send `Authenticated`'
        '403': 
          description: 'You do not have necessary permissions for the resource'
```

You can copy&paste it to https://editor.swagger.io to check out the results.

There are also several examples in the Swagger Editor web with more complex security configurations which could help you.

**Important:** In this example, API consumers must include the "Bearer" prefix as part of the token value. For example, when using Swagger UI's "Authorize" dialog, you need to enter `Bearer your_token` instead of just `your_token`.

[image: Swagger UI's Authorization dialog]

Comment: I don't see how you tell the editor what user and password or Basic token to send so you can get a 200. Am I missing something?

Comment: OK, nevermind. Apparently the "Authenticate" is something you can click on to get a login form.

Comment: So how do i set a value to the token? i tried curl -x get --header "Authorization: apiKey=123" but nothing happened

Comment: @Gobliins you want `curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer your_token"`, where `your_token` is your bearer token. E.g. `curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" "http://localhost/secure-endpoint"`

Comment: Ah yes thx, but what i dont get is when the connection between the header and the swagger security-definition is happening. Where and when is the validation? I could send this header token just without the security definition at all, where is the use of it?

Comment: @david-lopez have you tried to generate a SDK by swagger-codegen with these Security Definitions? Because while Swagger 2.0 Specification accepts these YAML and validates it. Swagger-codegen v2.1.6 generates an SDK without anyway possible to `token` into the function and appends to Authorization header. Mostly because specification and related not support JWT (Authorization Header) natively.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work well with Swagger UI - clicking "Authorize" and providing a bare token will generate "Try it out" curl examples with `-H "Authorization: foo"` instead of `-H "Authorization: Bearer foo"` like the OpenAPI 3 answer

Comment: Workaround for me was to put Bearer xxxxxxxx as the key in the UI authorization box. This worked, though the drawback is telling users to manually enter Bearer and then the key. Alternatively, you can modify your function/method for returning the API key to included the Bearer prefix as part of the key.

Comment: I have used the same code but getting below error 
**Operation accepts API keys transported in a header over network**
Also, any idea how to represent empty security? (means no auth token for some operations). Used below code
**security: []**
Got below error
**The security section of the operation 'options' contains an empty array**

Answer (score 109):

### Bearer authentication in OpenAPI 3.x

[OpenAPI 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md) and later versions support Bearer/JWT authentication natively. It's defined like this:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT  # optional, for documentation purposes only

security:
  - bearerAuth: []
```

This is supported in Swagger UI 3.4.0+ and Swagger Editor 3.1.12+ (again, for OpenAPI 3.x specs only!).

UI will display the "Authorize" button, which you can click and enter the bearer token (just the token itself, without the "Bearer " prefix). After that, "try it out" requests will be sent with the `Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx` header.

### Adding the `Authorization` header programmatically (Swagger UI 3.x+)

If you use Swagger UI and, for some reason, need to add the `Authorization` header programmatically instead of having the users click "Authorize" and enter the token, you can use the `requestInterceptor`. This solution is for **Swagger UI 3.x+**; UI 2.x used a different technique.

```javascript
// index.html

const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "https://your.server.com/swagger.json",
  ...

  requestInterceptor: (req) => {
    req.headers.Authorization = "Bearer xxxxxxx"
    return req
  }
})
```

Comment: How do I implement this in flask-restplus generated swagger documentation ?

Comment: I doubt if answer aligns with the question that was asked.

Comment: by doing this im getting no routes matches error

Comment: This one worked for me, it`s documented here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/

Comment: Is there a way to add the token programmatically in swagger UI. requestInterceptor doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 39):

## Posting 2024 answer in JSON using openapi 3.0.0:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  ...
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "/"
    }
  ],
  ...
  "paths": {
    "/skills": {
      "put": {
        "security": [
           {
              "bearerAuth": []
           }
        ],
       ...
  },


  "components": {        
    "securitySchemes": {
      "bearerAuth": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer",
        "bearerFormat": "JWT"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :-))

Comment: While reading swagger docs I can't get where the token endpoint in this scheme is

Comment: @Kakash1hatake You need to add it as a GET request with two parameters (username, password). The response will be the token.

Comment: @vitaly-sazanovich No, you don't see the point. When schema is oauth2 - it has dedicated **authorizationUrl** parameter to hold the endpoint address where to get then token. And bearer schema lacks it. But I suppose that it is used with external identity provider, so token is generated there

Answer (score 22):

**Why "Accepted Answer" works... but it wasn't enough for me**

This works in the specification. At least `swagger-tools` (version 0.10.1) validates it as a valid.

But if you are using other tools like `swagger-codegen` (version 2.1.6) you will find some difficulties, even if the client generated contains the Authentication definition, like this:

```
this.authentications = {
  'Bearer': {type: 'apiKey', 'in': 'header', name: 'Authorization'}
};
```

There is no way to pass the token into the header before method(endpoint) is called. Look into this function signature:

```
this.rootGet = function(callback) { ... }
```

This means that, I only pass the callback (in other cases query parameters, etc) without a token, which leads to a incorrect build of the request to server.

**My alternative**

Unfortunately, it's not "pretty" but it works until I get JWT Tokens support on Swagger.

Note: which is being discussed in

- [security: add support for Authorization header with Bearer
  authentication scheme #583](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/583)
- [Extensibility of security
  definitions? #460](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/460)

So, it's handle authentication like a standard header. On `path` object append an header paremeter:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Based on "Basic Auth Example"
  description: >
    An example for how to use Auth with Swagger.

host: localhost
schemes:
  - http
  - https
paths:
  /:
    get:
      parameters:
        - 
          name: authorization
          in: header
          type: string
          required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Will send `Authenticated`'
        '403': 
          description: 'You do not have necessary permissions for the resource'
```

This will generate a client with a new parameter on method signature:

```
this.rootGet = function(authorization, callback) {
  // ...
  var headerParams = {
    'authorization': authorization
  };
  // ...
}
```

To use this method in the right way, just pass the "full string"

```
// 'token' and 'cb' comes from elsewhere
var header = 'Bearer ' + token;
sdk.rootGet(header, cb);
```

And works.

Comment: "token comes from elsewhere"... I'm interested in the elsewhere. What when you logged got directed to your login and redirected to your swagger api, how can you use the access token you received?

Answer (score 1):

By using requestInterceptor, it worked for me:

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  ...
  requestInterceptor: (req) => {
    req.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + req.headers.Authorization;
    return req;
  },
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My Hackie way to solve this was by modifying the swagger.go file in the echo-swagger package in my case:

At the bottom of the file update the window.onload function to include a requestInterceptor which correctly formats the token.

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "{{.URL}}",
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
  validatorUrl: null,
  presets: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
    SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
  ],
  plugins: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
  ,
  layout: "StandaloneLayout",
  requestInterceptor: (req) => {
    req.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + req.headers.Authorization
  return req
  }
})

window.ui = ui
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solving this from laravel 7x ("openapi": "3.0.0"), edit your config\l5-swagger.php with the following codes

```
'securityDefinitions' => [
                'securitySchemes' => [
                    'bearerAuth' => [ 
                        'type' => 'http',
                        'scheme' => 'bearer',
                        'bearerFormat' => 'JWT', 
                    ], 
                ],
```

then you can add this as a security annotation for your endpoint:

```
*security={
     *{
     *"bearerAuth": {}},
     *},
```