# How to put header information in swagger json

Tags: json, rest, api, swagger

I followed the following link from swagger documentation to create swagger json for my rest api.

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-request-body/

In my rest api, I have request body and  http headers like Content-Type and Authorization that go along with the service request.

I was wondering if there is a way to include request body and http header information in the swagger json ? I don't see that information in the swagger docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header of requests and responses is defined by the `consumes` and `produces` keywords, respectively. They can be specified on the operation level or on the root level of the spec.

The `Authorization` header is defined using the `securityDefinitions` and `security` keywords. OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 supports Basic authentication, API keys and OAuth 2.

Other headers can be defined as [`in: header` parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/#header-parameters).

For example, if an operation POSTs JSON and uses Basic auth, you can describe it as follows:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

securityDefinitions:   # Authorization, part 1
  basicAuth:
    type: basic

paths:
  /something:
    post:
      summary: POST some JSON
      consumes:
        - application/json  # Request Content-Type
      produces:
        - application/json  # Response Content-Type
      security:
        - basicAuth: []     # Authorization, part 2
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Something'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

Relevant documentation:
[MIME Types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/mime-types/)
[Authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/)
[Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/)

Comment: Is there a way to specify Authorization header with bearer token in swagger spec 2.0 ?

Comment: @Hary: Assuming you mean standalone bearer tokens (not as part of OAuth 2 flow) - in 2.0 you would define it as an [API key](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/), and the word `Bearer ` is considered part of the key value. The latest version, OpenAPI 3.0, supports Bearer auth natively. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32910065/113116) for details.