# How do we represent in swagger documentation how to pass jwt token to an endpoint?

Tags: flask, swagger-2.0, flask-restful, flask-restplus

On my Flask-restplus swagger documentation I have defined an endpoint that gets me list of public ip address, I have learned that I can define a model

```
resource_fields = api.model('Resource', {
    'name': fields.String,
})
```

but I have also learned that I can use parser:

```
parser = api.parser()
parser.add_argument('param', type=int, help='Some param', location='form')
parser.add_argument('in_files', type=FileStorage, location='files')


@api.route('/with-parser/', endpoint='with-parser')
class WithParserResource(restplus.Resource):
    @api.expect(parser)
    def get(self):
        return {}
```

which one should I use, to pass `JWT` token ?
as what I want to pass is a header
so in curl that would be `curl -X GET -H "AUTHORIZATION: JWT some_xyz_token" http://url/api/doc`

Comment: You should probably use [`Authorization: Bearer xyz`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33281233/113116), not `Authorization: JWT xyz`. Related: [How can I represent 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' in a Swagger Spec (swagger.json)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32910065/113116)

Comment: Yes I came across the post just a while back ..  @Helen I already tried that, and it didn't worked. when I hit the "Try Out" in swagger UI, it hangs forever , showing the dot based progress bar... and nothing in terminal.

Comment: I have also tried this approach: http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger.html?highlight=headers#headers

Comment: if I run curl in terminal `-H "Authorization: JWT"` works but `-H "Authorization: Bearer"` does not work. although I had a look at documentation it should work