# How to define header parameters in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi

In OpenAPI (Swagger) 2.0, we could define header parameters like so:

```yaml
paths:
  /post:
    post:
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: X-username
```

But in OpenAPI 3.0.0, parameters are replaced by request bodies, and I cannot find a way to define header parameters, which would further be used for authentication.

What is the correct way to define request headers in OpenAPI 3.0.0?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In OpenAPI 3.0, header parameters are defined in the same way as in OpenAPI 2.0, except the `type` has been replaced with `schema`:

```yaml
paths:
  /post:
    post:
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: X-username
          schema:
            type: string
```

When in doubt, check out the [Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/) guide.

> But in Swagger 3.0.0 parameters are replaced by request bodies.

This is only true for form and body parameters. Other parameter types (path, query, header) are still defined as `parameters`.

> define header parameters, which would further be used for authentication.

A better way to define authentication-related parameters is to use `securitySchemes` rather than define these parameters explicitly in `parameters`. Security schemes are used for parameters such as API keys, app ID/secret, etc. In your case:

```yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    usernameHeader:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: X-Username

paths:
  /post:
    post:
      security:
        - usernameHeader: []
      ...
```

Comment: But this API is to send the username and password to a third party for authenticating the login and in return sends the token ID which I would further use in bearer authentication value for other APIs, would that still be a good idea to add in component?

Comment: It's up to you really. I would define [Bearer auth as a security scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45471010/113116) but the initial login request with regular parameters.

Comment: That's what I did and yes it worked for me, thanks Helen, instant help appreciated..

Comment: I need to pass in something like `Usage-Data: kind=sdk, name=nodejs, version=1.2.3` via the header. This never changes and I want it to be sent on all requests for all paths. How can I do this? @Helen

Comment: @RodrigoGomez-Palacio please [ask a new question](/questions/ask?tags=openapi).