# Right method to define Bearer token authentication in swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger-2.0, bearer-token

I am working on the definition of a service contract with swagger 2.0.
my question is : 
what is the right method to define Bearer token authentication in swagger 2.0?
FYI : I have find to methods in internet what is the right one?

**method 1 :**
securityDefinitions:
  Bearer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
security:
  - Bearer: []

**method 2 :**
securityDefinitions:
  ApiKeyAuth:
    type: apiKey
    name: X-API-Key
    in: header
security:
  - ApiKeyAuth: []

Comment: The 1st example is correct. Possible duplicate of [How can I represent 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' in a Swagger Spec (swagger.json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910065/how-can-i-represent-authorization-bearer-token-in-a-swagger-spec-swagger-j)

Comment: thank you ... it's right