# Swagger-Net and Bearer Token Authorization

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-net

We are using Swagger-Net with Bearer Token Authorization as follows:

`c.ApiKey("Authorization", "header", "Bearer Token Authentication");`

The request needs to be sent in the format "Bearer [bearertoken]", and I have verified this does work correctly when pasted in this format into the "API Key" authorization textbox.  The Curl shows it being passed in the header as `-H "Authorization: Bearer [token]` and the API request succeeds.

Is there any way to automatically send a known token along with every API request?  Or asked another way, is there any way to pre-fill this dynamically created API Key textbox with a known string to simplify the process for the end using testing our API?

Comment: In Swagger UI you do this by using [`requestInterceptor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45471010/113116). Maybe Swagger-Net has a config for that.

Comment: @Helen Thanks, does this approach require swapping out index.html with a fully custom version?  I know I can inject JavaScript with Swagger-Net.

Comment: No idea, I haven't used Swagger-Net myself.

Comment: You could inject the custom javascript and UI and add a section to populate the Authorization header textbox on all APIs